# Add custom view to fragment layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a View Class which i want to add to my Fragment, but i cant figure out how to do it.

Here is my fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pong, container, true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout pongField = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pongGameField);
        pongField.addView(new SingleTouchEventView(getActivity(), null));
    }
```

I try to add the SingleTouchEventView to the fragment in the onViewCreated method of the fragment, but it doesnt work.

Here is the error:

```
12-18 14:49:11.479 18177-18177/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3439)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3310)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3255)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3231)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 14:49:34.129 18177-18177/com.example.pymdev.pym I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18177 SIG: 9
```

Please help, how can i add my View to the fragment layout properly?

Comment: add it in `onCreateView` event.

Comment: That doesnt help, it still crashes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A boolean indicating whether the inflated layout should be attached to the ViewGroup (the second parameter) during inflation.
>
> (In this case, this is false because the system is already inserting the inflated layout into the container—passing true would create a redundant view group in the final layout.)

For more detail refer [to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Use this

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pong, container,false);
```

instead of

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pong, container,true);
```

Comment: This does work for me. However, my custom view is a canvas where i can drag around a rectangle with touch. With this solution i can drag it under the top Toolbar, so it seems the canvas is not bounded by the view in the fragment where it should be...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pong, container, true);

 RelativeLayout pongField = (RelativeLayout) view .findViewById(R.id.pongGameField);
        pongField.addView(new SingleTouchEventView(getActivity(), null));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: new SingleTouchEventView(getActivity(), null) you are using Activity context to create view, It will not work in Fragment